# How to remove an element from the flow?

Tags: css

I know `position: absolute` will pop an element from the flow and it stops interacting with its neighbors.

What other ways are there to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean remove it from the page entirely, or just make it invisible? What do you mean by "interacting with its neighbors?"

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i just thought there was a way to do it and i couldn't remember so i turned to stackoverflow :) position:absolute works but i was just wondering

Comment: Useful answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11917186/11298742

Answer (score 63, accepted):

None?

I mean, other than removing it from the layout entirely with `display: none`, I'm pretty sure that's it.

Are you facing a particular situation in which `position: absolute` is not a viable solution?

Comment: `position: absolute` causes repainting on scrolling, which is bad for performance on mobile

Comment: This is not the answer a user expects to get when coming here as title reads "remove from the flow". `display: none` completely removes the element not only from the flow.

Answer (score 135):

One trick that makes `position:absolute` more palatable to me is to make its parent `position:relative`.  Then the child will be 'absolute' relative to the position of the parent.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mC7QM/)

Comment: In some cases adding `position:absolute` to the parent causes zIndex to fail (ignored), meaning that the detached element can be still painted over by some in-the-flow elements. Removing `position:absolute` from the parent has help me to solve this.

Answer (score 45):

Another option is to set `height: 0; overflow: visible;` to an element, though it won't be really outside the flow and therefore may break [margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing).

Comment: @Jessica, use `::before` pseudo element with absolute positioning to emulate the background.

Comment: With this approach the element will also take a [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) cell if it is in a grid parent, which is inconvenient.

Answer (score 7):

`position: fixed;` will also "pop" an element out of the flow, as you say. :)

`position: absolute` must be accompanied by a position. e.g. `top: 1rem; left: 1rem`

`position: fixed` however, will place the element where it would normally appear according to the document flow, but prevent it from moving after that. It also effectively set's the height to 0px (with regards to the dom) so that the next element shifts up over it.

This can be pretty cool, because you can set `position: fixed; z-index: 1` (or whatever z-index you need) so that it "pops" over the next element.

This is especially useful for fixed position headers that stay at the top when you scroll, for example.

Comment: position: fixed z-index: 1 brings it out of flow but the element stays in fixed position. It does not scroll. I want an element to bring out of the flow and also scroll.

Answer (score 5):

There's `display: none`, but I think that might be a bit more than what you're looking for.

Comment: But even then, it's still "in the neighborhood".. absolute position relative to the body is the only way to have full control over it's position. Keep in mind if it's parent is declared as relative then it's absolute origin is relative to that - you'd have to append the element to document.body or non-relatative declared element in that case.

Comment: What? Position is not relevant if the element isn't even *displayed*.

Comment: In Firefox, validation messages for inputs with `display: none` appear in a nonsensical location (at the top of the screen, covering up the tabs).  It seems undisplayed elements are truly positionless, at least in that browser.

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of completeness: 
The `float` property removes a element from the flow of the HTML too, e.g.

```css
float: right
```

Answer (score 3):

Floating it will reorganise the flow but position: absolute is the only way to completely remove it from the flow of the document.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is several years old, but what I think you're trying to do is get it so where a large element, like an image doesn't interfere with the height of a div?

I just ran into something similar, where I wanted an image to overflow a div, but I wanted it to be at the end of a string of text, so I didn't know where it would end up being.

A solution I figured out was to put the margin-bottom: -element's height, so if the image is 20px hight,

`margin-bottom: -20px;
 vertical-align: top;`

for example.

That way it floated over the outside of the div, and stayed next to the last word in the string.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this:

```
position: relative;
clear: both;
```

I use it when I can't use absolute position, for example in printing when you use `page-break-after: always;` works fine only with `position:relative`.